How do I make a multiline paragraph element dynamically shrink horizontally to remove white space?
Let me explain... I'm building out a representation of a SMS chain in html. Here is what I've got:


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap");

body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 1080px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
}

article {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: fit-content;
    max-width: 75%;
}

article p {
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

article.them {
    color: black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

article.me {
    color: white;
    background-color: darkblue;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

/* Smaller margin between consecutive messages from the same sender */
article.me + article.me,
article.them + article.them {
    margin-top: 3px;
}

/* Standard margin between different senders */
article.me + article.them,
article.them + article.me {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
<body>
    <section>
        <article class="them">
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="me">
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="me">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Nostrum tempore excepturi dolore nam? Odio architecto
                tempora maiores corrupti nihil autem necessitatibus natus
                consequuntur adipisci hic nisi quaerat voluptate, incidunt
                beatae?
            </p>
        </article>
        <article class="them">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Repellat officia delectus sequi quo quas!
            </p>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>



When the text bubble has only a few words, it shrinks to the appropriate width. This is because the article is set to shrink to the width of the content with both display: inline-block; and width: fit-content;. But with the multi-line text bubbles, the bubble will always be the maximum width (75% of the section width). This is because the paragraph will take up the full allowed width, despite the fact the line broke early to keep words together. This leaves some white space off to the right of the multiline text bubbles, depending on your screen width. I want the paragraph element to shrink width-wise to remove the excess white space left from a line break. Any idea if this is possible with CSS?

If your goal is to remove white-space then you can add text-align: justify use that if it aligns with your needs.

Thank you @Meet This does indeed get rid of the white space, but I'm looking to shrink the paragraph (and consequently the box) rather than expand the text.

This solution might be helpful check it out

For making a multiline paragraph element dynamically shrink horizontally to remove white space?

Use inline-block for the article class to allow the text to shrink based on it's content, and insure the text does not exceed the actual width.


Use max-width to limit the horizontal expansion, but avoid pre-wrap if it's forcing unnecessary vertical expansion.


Ensure white-space: 'nowrap' is not used unless you want single-line bubbles.

Here is output image it's working on my side
Here is the adjusted code:
CSS
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap");

        body {
            background-color: black;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            font-size: 2rem;
        }

        section {
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: white;
            max-width: 1080px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        article {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            width: auto;
            max-width: 75%;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        article p {
            margin: 0;
            display: inline;
            white-space: normal;
        }

        article.them {
            color: black;
            background-color: lightgray;
            align-self: flex-start;
        }

        article.me {
            color: white;
            background-color: darkblue;
            align-self: flex-end;
        }

        article.me+article.me,
        article.them+article.them {
            margin-top: 3px;
        }

        article.me+article.them,
        article.them+article.me {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

HTML
<body>
    <section>
        <article class="them">
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="me">
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="me">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Nostrum tempore excepturi dolore nam? Odio architecto
                tempora maiores corrupti nihil autem necessitatibus natus
                consequuntur adipisci hic nisi quaerat voluptate, incidunt
                beatae?
            </p>
        </article>
        <article class="them">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Repellat officia delectus sequi quo quas!
            </p>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>

This code should be shrink the text bubble horizontally based on the content. The bubble will wrap only when required, and it won’t exceed the maximum width of 75%.
Hopefully this will work for you if you have any further issue please let me know, thanks.
